# Removing single quote from dataframe

Tags: r

I have single quote (`' '`) in every item of my dataframe, `mydf`. How can I remove those single quotes?
For example, if I print `colnames(mydf)`, I get `'column1'`, `'column2'` and so forth.

I just want `column1`, `column2` without any quotes. I want same for all the vectors in those columns.

Comment: it's a data frame and not a matrix, correct? please add the `dput` or something

Comment: @rawr Yes, it is a dataframe.

Comment: You mean you have single quotes inside double quote in the output? R typically prints out character values in quotes. What are you planning to do with the unquoted values? A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output would be most helpful.

Comment: print(colnames(mydf), quote=F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This technique should work

```
x <- data.frame(c1=c("'hello'", "'goodbye'"),
            c2=c("'why'","'mumble'"))
names(x) <- c("'c1'", "'c2'")

names(x) <- substr(names(x), 2, nchar(names(x))-1)
x <- as.matrix(x)
x <- substr(x, 2, nchar(x)-1)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
```

I've edited my original answer to show how you could convert the data frame to a matrix and back to a data frame.